# Direct Integral: Measurability

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Borel space $\Omega$.

Consider plain functions:
$$\eta,\vartheta\in\mathcal{F}(\Omega):=\{\eta:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}\}$$

The implication is wrong:
$$|\eta|,|\vartheta|,|\eta+\vartheta|\in\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\implies|a\eta+b\vartheta|\in\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\quad(a,b\in\mathbb{C})$$

As example I had in mind:
$$\eta:=2-1_\mathbb{V}\quad \vartheta:=i1$$

Is the implication also wrong:
$$|a\eta+b\vartheta|\in\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\quad(a,b\in\mathbb{C})\implies|\alpha\eta+\beta\vartheta|\in\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\quad(\alpha,\beta\in\mathcal{L}^\infty)$$

What could be an example?

Comment: Explain notation, please.  What is $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Sure: $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ shall denote the Borel functions. $\mathcal{L}^\infty$ shall denote the bounded Borel functions. Ah and: $\mathbb{V}$ shall denote a Vitali set. Did I miss something yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication is true.  Use polarization.

Suppose $|a\eta+b\vartheta|$ is measurable for all complex $a,b$.  Taking $a=1, b=0$ we see that $|\eta|$ is measurable, and likewise so is $|\vartheta|$.  Next, taking $a=b=1$, we see that
$$|\eta + \vartheta|^2 = |\eta|^2 + |\vartheta|^2 + 2 \operatorname{Re}(\overline\eta \vartheta)$$
is also measurable.  So $\operatorname{Re}(\overline\eta \vartheta)$ is measurable.  Applying the same trick to
$$|\eta + i\vartheta|^2 = |\eta|^2 + |\vartheta|^2 - 2 \operatorname{Im}(\overline\eta \vartheta)$$
we see that $\operatorname{Im}(\overline\eta \vartheta)$ is also measurable.  Now for arbitrary measurable $\alpha, \beta$ we have
$$|\alpha \eta + \beta \vartheta|^2 = |\alpha|^2 |\eta|^2 + \operatorname{Re}(\overline\alpha \beta) \operatorname{Re}(\overline\eta \vartheta) - \operatorname{Im}(\overline\alpha \beta) \operatorname{Im}(\overline\eta \vartheta) + |\beta|^2 |\vartheta|^2$$ 
so we see that $|\alpha \eta + \beta \vartheta|^2$ is measurable, hence so is its square root $|\alpha \eta + \beta \vartheta|$.

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you!!! That even immediately extends to Banach space valued functions. :D

Comment: By the way, I guess it shall read: $\operatorname{Re}(\overline{\eta}\vartheta)$, $\operatorname{Im}(\overline{\eta}\vartheta)$, $\operatorname{Re}(\overline{\alpha}\beta)$, $\operatorname{Im}(\overline{\alpha}\beta)$?

Comment: @Freeze_S: Oops, yes it should.  I'm going to sleep now but please feel free to edit.

Comment: Alright. Thank you again for the quick answer!! :) Good night!